# Showing [hello-world.upload] Error 2 in contiki

Tags: contiki

I am trying to upload hello-world in **Micaz** using **Contiki**.
I followed these steps

```
user@instant-contiki:~$ cd contiki/examples/hello-world

user@instant-contiki:~/contiki/examples/hello-world$ make TARGET=micaz hello-world
  CC        hello-world.c
  LD        hello-world.micaz
rm hello-world.co
user@instant-contiki:~/contiki/examples/hello-world$ make TARGET=micaz savetarget
saving Makefile.target
```

Finally while uploading I got the below error

```
user@instant-contiki:~/contiki/examples/hello-world$ make hello-world.upload
using saved target 'micaz'
avr-objcopy -O srec hello-world.micaz hello-world.srec
uisp -dprog=mib510 -dserial=/dev/ttyS0 -dpart=ATmega128 --wr_fuse_h=0xd1 --wr_fuse_e=ff --erase --upload if=hello-world.srec --verify
Error: Permission denied
 -> /dev/ttyS0
make: *** [hello-world.upload] Error 1
rm hello-world.srec
```

I have seen many Stackoverflow questions regarding the same .
But those workaround is not solving my issues.

Am I doing anything wrong.

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the problem is about permission.

Try "**sudo** make hello-world.upload"

And if you use Instant contiki 2.7 and it is your first time compiling with Micaz,

you may have another problem about "make: uisp: Command not found"

Then, refer following link.

http://iotnet.blogspot.kr/2014/07/contiki-micaz-2-uisp-command-not-found.html